# Grouped Product display by colour/size

Tags: theme, grouped-products

I'm looking for help to achieve the following listing of grouped products (Magento CE 1.7.02)
[image: magento grouped display] The idea is that the user can select (say) 10 Black Small, 6 Black XL, 4 Navy Medium, etc, etc.

An added complication is that the price/cart should update as values are entered into the Qty fields

Any suggestions welcomed.
Thanks, Eddie

Comment: Please break this out into multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it on `https://promovement.pfconcept.com` I have use multidimensional matrix concept to implement this.

And also you have to modify `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` class `addProduct()` function. You have to implement `addProduct()` using `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'm sure more people than just me would be interested in seeing some code examples as to how you did this.

Comment: Im looking to do something like this. Please update.